# detect a "string character" after "another" with characters between the 2 patterns

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have this type of data :

```
x <- "30098 HGQX0080 ; 30098 **HJFC0230** ; 30098 HGMA0030 ; 30098 ZZQX0270 ; 30098 ZZQX1880 ; 30099 ZCQH0010 ; 30099 YYYY6000 ; 30106 ZCQH0010 ; 30106 YYYY6000 ; 30163 **HGSA0010** ; 30163 ZZQX1880"
```

my question is : I need to detect "**HGSA0010**" knowing that "**HJFC0230**" is present before the occurence of this code.

I try this type of function :

```
str_detect(x,"HJFC0230(?=HGSA0010)")
```

but it's not working because there are this character " ; 30098 HGMA0030 ; 30098 ZZQX0270 ; 30098 ZZQX1880 ; 30099 ZCQH0010 ; 30099 YYYY6000 ; 30106 ZCQH0010 ; 30106 YYYY6000 ; " in between. So it did not work.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `grepl` with the pattern `\bHJFC0230\b.+\bHGSA0010\b`:

```r
x <- "30098 HGQX0080 ; 30098 HJFC0230 ; 30098 HGMA0030 ; 30098 ZZQX0270 ; 30098 ZZQX1880 ; 30099 ZCQH0010 ; 30099 YYYY6000 ; 30106 ZCQH0010 ; 30106 YYYY6000 ; 30163 HGSA0010 ; 30163 ZZQX1880"
grepl("\\bHJFC0230\\b.+\\bHGSA0010\\b", x)

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: than It's working well

Comment: You should ask a new question.